# how to get automaticaly the number of colors and the colors returned from a dendrogram clustering hierarchy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

scikit-learn gives [an example of python code to generate a dendogram](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-agglomerative-dendrogram-py). I copy/paste this code bellow. This code generates a dendogram. This dendogram display 3 differents colors: blue, green, and orange.

**Question:** which code associated with this dendogram code example, could automaticaly deliver:

- the **number of colors** generated by the dendrogram ?
- the **list of those** of those colors (or their code number) ?

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering


def plot_dendrogram(model, **kwargs):
    # Create linkage matrix and then plot the dendrogram

    # create the counts of samples under each node
    counts = np.zeros(model.children_.shape[0])
    n_samples = len(model.labels_)
    for i, merge in enumerate(model.children_):
        current_count = 0
        for child_idx in merge:
            if child_idx < n_samples:
                current_count += 1  # leaf node
            else:
                current_count += counts[child_idx - n_samples]
        counts[i] = current_count

    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack(
        [model.children_, model.distances_, counts]
    ).astype(float)

    # Plot the corresponding dendrogram
    dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# setting distance_threshold=0 ensures we compute the full tree.
model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=0, n_clusters=None)

model = model.fit(X)
plt.title("Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram")
# plot the top three levels of the dendrogram
plot_dendrogram(model, truncate_mode="level", p=3)
plt.xlabel("Number of points in node (or index of point if no parenthesis).")
plt.show()
```

[image: dendrogram image returned by the above code]

Comment: are you asking for a list of the color themselves in matplotlib? Or the nodes in the linkage matrix?

Comment: the numbers of colors displayed, and their "identification" as a code name, a code, ...

Comment: you mean like RGB?

Comment: any color code (like those given by matplotlib) would be enought. Nevertheless, would be greatfull to get code color as [web color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html), the number of colors is determined by `color_threshold`, which is defaulted to `0.7*max(Z[:,2])`. So you only have to find the number of merges higher than that:

First modify your code to get the linkage matrix:

```
def get_linkage(model):
    # Create linkage matrix

    # create the counts of samples under each node
    counts = np.zeros(model.children_.shape[0])
    n_samples = len(model.labels_)
    for i, merge in enumerate(model.children_):
        current_count = 0
        for child_idx in merge:
            if child_idx < n_samples:
                current_count += 1  # leaf node
            else:
                current_count += counts[child_idx - n_samples]
        counts[i] = current_count

    linkage_matrix = np.column_stack(
        [model.children_, model.distances_, counts]
    ).astype(float)
    return linkage_matrix


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data

# setting distance_threshold=0 ensures we compute the full tree.
model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=0, n_clusters=None)

model = model.fit(X)
linkage_matrix = get_linkage(model)
```

Then calculate the number of colors from it:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import cut_tree
color_threshold = 0.7 * max(linkage_matrix[:, 2])
n_color = 1 + len(np.unique(cut_tree(linkage_matrix, height = color_threshold)))
color_codes = ['C' + str(i) for i in range(n_color)] # this is simply the matplotlib default color code
```

Comment: thank you [Z Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14751619/z-li). Probably, there might be a way to avoid to repeat linkage matrix builing code puting it in a function, and then use it first to plot the dendrogram, and second to calculate the number of colors (and get code colors). Anyway, thank a lot for your help.

Comment: you can simply use the above code to get the linkage matrix and use `dendrogram(linkage_matrix, **kwargs)` to plot it.